# Prevent columns from having same value in record

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm working with PostgreSQL 10. I'd like to have a table that allows for the same value in a column, but not in the row. The table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE teams
(
  team_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  team_lead character varying(250) NOT NULL,  
  member1 character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  member2 character varying(250),
  member3 character varying(250)
  )
```

This would be allowed:

```
| team_lead     |  member1     | member2       |
------------------------------------------------
| Jane Doe      | Bill Smith   | Shirley Green |
| Jane Doe      | Carol Lewis  | John  Doe     |
```

This would NOT:

```
| team_lead  | member1     | member2       |
--------------------------------------------
| Jane Doe   | Jane Doe    | Shirley Green |
| Bill Smith | Carol Lewis | Bill Smith    |
```

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normalize your model and then you can apply a simple unique constraint

Comment: what would be an example of the constraint?

Comment: I think this is an fine exemplar of a common anti-pattern with an answer showing the proper relational solution. As such it should be kept, not closed and deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a "many-to-many" relationship. One person can be a member of multiple teams and a team has multiple members. One way to model this, could be:

```
create table person
(
   person_id integer primary key, 
   name text not null
);

create table team
(
  team_id integer primary key, 
  name text not null
);

create table team_member
(
  team_id integer not null references team, 
  person_id integer not null references person,
  person_role text not null check (team_role in ('lead', 'member')), 

   -- each person can only be assigned to a team once
  primary key (team_id, person_id)
);
```